# Limit of the commutator of two elements?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Given a Lie group $G$ such the $\mathfrak{g}$ denoted its Lie algebra. Let $[g,g']_{G}$ the commutator of two elements $g,g' \in G$ and denoted by $[X,X']_{\mathfrak{g}}$ the Lie bracket of two elements $X,X' \in \mathfrak{g},$ and let $\gamma$ a one-parameter of $G$ given by $\gamma(t)=e^{tX}$ for some $X\in \mathfrak{g} $.

I look for reference where I can find the proof of the following result 
$$[X,X']_{\mathfrak{g}}= \lim_{t\to 0}\, [g.e^{tX},g'.e^{tX'}]_{G}. $$
Or in general, $$[X,X']_{\mathfrak{g}}= \lim_{t\to 0}\, [g.\gamma(t),g'.\gamma(t)]_{G}$$
for a one-parameter $\gamma: (\mathbb R,+) \longrightarrow  G$  of $G$.

Thank you in advance

Comment: The proof is really easy if $G\subset GL_n(\bf R)$ is a subgroup. Just write $exp tX= id+ tX+t^2X^2+o(t^2)$ and compute the commutator. The general case follows from the fact that any Lie algebra is a Lie subalgebra of the Lie algebar of matrices.

Comment: thank you Thomas, is that you know a reference that I can find this type of result?

Comment: Any good book on Lie groups (Helgason, Postnikov) does the job. If you read french the book by Mneimné-Testard in an excellent introduction for beginners.

Comment: @ THOMAS. Ok thanks